# How to get access to Google script functions in Add on GCP standard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, publish, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

Kindly I wrote an Add-on and it was working smoothly without any errors, but after I have changed its GCP to standard I started to get errors on the lines that contains code of Google functions that the code has not permission, of course the authorization process replied with successful message, and all the required scopes are added in "oauthScopes" appsscript.json

functions like creating new folder in Google drive.

I need help in how to get back access permission for Google functions.

**The error message:** *There was an error while loading /project/ProjectNumber/logs?authuser=0. Please try again.*

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding the OAuth scopes to appsscript.json you have to add them to the  OAuth consent screen and the Marketplace SDK configuration. Also you have to enable the APIs for the advanced services used by your add-on.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project